# Grails - How to include subdirectories of lib in classpath?

Tags: grails

I have an application deployed and I need to include new jars during runtime.
I am currently doing it by placing the jars in the lib directory, but if I place them in some subdirectory of lib they are not loaded. 
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: I'm just curious what is the reason to include them at runtime manually and not make them a runtime dependency in BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: @lukelazarovic Because when I compile the application I don't know the dependencies and I need to add new functionality without recompiling it (just dropping the new jars and redeploying). Is there another option?